# Realm Async is not opening

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I am trying sync from my MongoDB Realm Cloud to local database for access.

I am following this instruction
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/sync-data/#ios-sync-data

here is my mongoDB Realm screen shot. It shows the items i want to sync with the partioningKey.

[image: ![enter image description here]

here is my code

```js
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     fetchStoreItems()
}

  func fetchStoreItems(){
        let user = app.currentUser()

        let partitionValue = "store=walmart"
        
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: user!.configuration(partitionValue: partitionValue),
        callback: { (maybeRealm, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)")
            }
            guard let realm = maybeRealm else {
                fatalError("realm is nil!")
            }
            // realm opened
            // All tasks in the realm
            let storeItems = maybeRealm!.objects(Item.self)
                     let tasksThatBeginWithA = storeItems.filter("name beginsWith 'R'")
                     print("these are the item amount", tasksThatBeginWithA.count)
        })
    }
```

Authentication works fine but fetching the data returns empty with this message

> Sync: Connection[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUwCF.png): Session[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUwCF.png): client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = true, async open = false, client reset = false

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: There could be a number of issues here. First, this is dangerous `Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: user!` please handle optionals as if they could be nil to  protect your code. Also, this `app.currentUser()` may not be resolving correctly.  This `let partitionValue = "store=walmart"` may not match the partition key in your Realm App Console - double check it. Please use `realm` after the guard instead of `maybeRealm!`. Are you stating `let storeItems` is nil?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're accessing the wrong object, but it's a little hard to tell by the question. Items is the highlighted object in the screen shot so it seems that's the one you're after  (?)

It looks like your database has two objects

```
Item
```

and

```
items
```

but your code is accessing the Item one

```
let storeItems = maybeRealm!.objects(Item.self)
```

not the `items` one.